# Nested abbreviation expansion with emmet in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, emmet

In sublime text with emmet plugin I can write 
[image] 
To get 
[image]
But if I want to generate some lorem or other tag  
[image] 
after pressing tab I go to the next list item 
[image]
how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to expand `lorem3`, instead of <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

When you expand abbreviation (especially like `ul>li*3`), Emmet generates tabstops (*fields* in terms of Sublime Text) in some important places assuming that you’re likely want to fill-up data in them (attribute values, tag contents etc.). So after you expand abbreviation you’re actually moving between tabstops with Tab/Shift-Tab. It’s a pity that ST does not displays decorations for tabstops.

You can simply press Esc key to quit tabstops mode and use Tab for expanding abbreviations.